# How to separate string into 3 seperate strings with unknown lengths

Tags: java, string

I am making a calculator program and want it to be able to use fractions like so: `7/8 * 3/4 or 11/12 - 1/10`.

I separate the 3 parts `firstValue`, `operation`, `secondValue`.

Now I need to figure out how to separate the fraction into 3 parts without spaces and the values in the fraction has an unexpected amount of digits like 3 and 30.

If it was a fraction like 3/4, I know I could have just separated it by splitting it into all of it's 3 symbols but it could be a fraction like 3/11 so just keeping the separation as a 3 won't work.

I also know I can't use `StringTokenizer` and separate using "/" or "". Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You probably would be better off tokenizing the string and converting fractions to decimals

Comment: In your example above, how can you tell that `7/8 * 3/4` doesn't actually mean `(7/8 * 3) / 4` ?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou 7/8 is one token, * is the second, 3/4 is the third. First I separate all tokens and then I separate 7/8 and 3/4.

Comment: Do you want `7, /, 8, *, 3, /, 4` all separately?

Comment: Are you looking at whitespace in your strings and using it to determine which bits of it are tokens?

Comment: @Bohemian I separated 7/8, *, and 3/4 already. What was trying to do is separate "7/8" and "3/4" like this: numerator = 7, denominator = 8. I also already got my answer from Sean Bright and I'm not sure why you are asking this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply split on word boundaries:

```
String[] parts = str.split("\\b");
```

This splits between word chars and non-word (and visa versa). Digits are considered "word chars".

This will take a String such as `"123/456"` and return an array `["123", "/", "456"]`.

Comment: Boundaries? just splitting into chars won't work(if that's what you meant)! What if it's like 7/20?

Comment: @TheLittleCoder it will work with numbers (and operators) too of any size. This doesn't split chars, it splits in word *boundaries*

Comment: Will it be like ["7", "/", "2", "0"]? That's not really what I need

Comment: @thelittlecoder I have updated the example in my answer to illustrate how it works. I suggest you try it for yourself in your code.

Comment: oh.... that makes more since after you explain it! That means I can just take the first part and third part of string and divide them

Comment: numerator = parts[1];?

Comment: @TheLittleCoder the numerator *is* the first part, ie `parts[0]` and the denominator *is* the third part, ie `parts[2]`.

Comment: oh, forgot. Thanks!

Comment: I would accept both answers but I think this one better and simpler!